# Project Euler #11"numbers in a grid" in Rust

Tags: programming-challenge, rust

To learn more about Rust, I implemented Project Euler #11 "Numbers in a grid". Contrary to some people, I prefer not having the actual data grid in my code, so I put it in a file, which I read in the beginning.

I'm wondering how 'Rustic' my code is. Specially I wonder about the following points:

- How to most concisely read a table of integers into a data structure? Is it possible to create an array of a certain size? Do I need all this `split`ing and `from_str` mapping?
- Have I handled the array indices in the right way? I'm not used to needing all this casting.
- I my `max` function sufficiently generic?

```
use std::io;
fn max(a:int, b:int) -> int {if a > b {a} else {b}}
fn main() {
    let n = 20;
    let mut ar:Vec<Vec<int>> = vec![];
    for line in io::stdin().lines() {
        let s = line.unwrap();
        let ss = s.as_slice().trim().split(' ');
        let xs:Vec<int> = ss.map(|s|from_str::<int>(s).unwrap()).collect();
        ar.push(xs);
    }
    let mut best = 0;
    for i in range(0i,n) {
        for j in range(0i,n) {
            for &(di, dj) in [(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1i)].iter() {
                if i+di*3 < n && j+dj*3 < n && j+dj*3 >= 0 {
                    let mut p = 1;
                    for k in range(0i,4) {
                        p *= ar[(i+di*k) as uint][(j+dj*k) as uint]
                    }
                    best = max(best, p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println!("{}", best);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like most people not actively involved in the language design, I'm still finding my feet with Rust as well, so take what I have to say with a large grain of salt.

You don't need to define your own `max` function: there is one already in the standard library, in `std::cmp` to be exact:

```
pub fn max<T: Ord>(v1: T, v2: T) -> T
```

This will work for anything that has an `impl Ord`, which `int` certainly does.

You can avoid the casts if you simply read everything in as a `uint` in the first place. In fact, it's probably a good idea to split up the code reading and parsing the file from the code that does the calculation. I'd write it something like:

```
use std::io;

fn read_grid(path: &str) -> Vec<Vec<uint>> {
    let path = Path::new(path);
    let mut file = io::BufferedReader::new(io::File::open(&path));
    let mut lines = file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap());
    let mut grid: Vec<Vec<uint>> = vec![];

    for line in lines {
        let option = line.as_slice().split(' ').map(|x| -> Option<uint> from_str(x.trim()));
        grid.push(option.filter(|x| x.is_some()).map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect());
    }
    grid
}
```

This will also skip over any non-convertible values (that is, anything that `from_str(x.trim())` gives `None` from.

I don't doubt there are still much better ways of writing this, but that's about where I'm at for now.

Comment: I don't think I can use `uint`, as my `dj` can be negative. At least, if `j` is `uint` and `dj` is `int`, I'll have to write `j+dj*3` someway different. I think.

Comment: `.map(|x| -> Option<uint> from_str(x.trim())).filter(|x| x.is_some()).map(|x| x.unwrap())` would be better as `.filter_map(|x| from_str::<uint>(x.trim())`. And once it’s done that way, the `::<uint>` part can be inferred, so it can be dropped too.

Comment: The [recommended style](http://aturon.github.io/style/imports.html#prefer-fully-importing-types-traits-while-module-qualifying-functions-rfc-) would also have `use std::io::{BufferedReader, File};`.

Comment: If you really wanted to mess with people, you could write the entire body of the function in one expression, `BufferedReader::new(File::open(&Path::new(path))).lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()[].split(' ').filter_map(|x| from_str(x.trim())).collect()).collect()`… (oh yeah, you can use `[]` where you used to have `.as_slice()`)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan You should write all of this up as an answer.